# Multiple defined linker error for getting static member variable template

Tags: c++, templates, variable-templates

When I have a class that can be boiled down to something like this:

```
// test.hpp
class Test{
public:
  template<typename T> static T value;
};

template<typename T> Test::value = {};
```

I can use this class when I only look up an instantiated `value` in one .cpp file. But when I try to use this in multiple .cpp files I get an already defined linker error.

```
//somefile1.cpp
include "test.hpp"
void fn(){
  int i = Test::value<int>;
}

// somefile2.cpp
include "test.hpp"
void otherfn(){
  // public static int value already defined in somefile1.obj
  int j = Test::value<int>;
}
```

Putting `template<typename T> Test::value = {}` into its own .cpp file gives an unresolved external error for all uses. What's the problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce. (after fixing syntax for definition of template variable). What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using VS2015, I guess its uses its default compiler.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in gcc, and creates weak symbol as expected. I suggest you actually fix your example to be correct syntax.